# How to install a SSL certificate on Tomcat with existing CSR?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

Is there a way to install an SSL certificate and make it work on Tomcat if I've already got these files?

```
wildcard.foo.com.crt
wildcard.foo.com.csr
wildcard.foo.com.key
```

All tutorials I found were generating their own CSR file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by somehow combining these 2 tutorials:

http://www.linuxweblog.com/blogs/sandip/20080725/importing-existing-ssl-key-and-certificate-tomcat
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/tsec_ssl_jsp_pkcs12.html

Basically what I had to do was:

1. Download OpenSSL for windows and add it to classpath to be able to use it in CMD
2. Convert .crt and .key into a .pkcs12 keystore file - have done that with the keytool located `Java\jre7\bin`
3. I've also done the other steps stated in the first link, to update cacerts, but I don't feel like that's needed, needs to be confirmed by someone else.
4. Edit the `server.xml` file that is in `conf` folder of Tomcat.
5. I then started the tomcat with the bat file example from the second link, not sure if that is required either. (Be sure you change the password to your own pwd that you used when creating the keystore file), as in example this is used: "endeca"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your certificates to the truststore of the JVM tomcat is using. This can be done, with keytool, or easyer with keystoreexplorer program. 
The truststore is the "cacerts" file inside the following folder:

```
Java\jre\lib\security
```

Once added there restart tomcat and you should be able to access your site, using the certificate.

Password for truststore uses to be "changeit"

UPDATE**:

Try with this command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /path/to/ca/ca.pem -alias CA_ALIAS -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

if it does not work, take a look to this url: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

And if that does not make it work, download keystoreexplorer. easy to use.

http://www.keystore-explorer.org/downloads.php

Regards

Comment: Sounds fair, any idea how to do it with the keytool?

Comment: I was able to put my cert into cacerts following this tutorial: http://www.linuxweblog.com/blogs/sandip/20080725/importing-existing-ssl-key-and-certificate-tomcat
but that doesn't change anything, I still can't connect to my app won port 8443. Any idea how can I check if what I did actually worked? I can only see that my entry is in the cacerts, but that's it.